# PHP echo position in codeigniter

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I'm a newbie to web development, so this might sound dumb.

I was trying to echo a form.

```
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo form_label($login_label, $login['id']); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo form_input($login); ?></td>    
  <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($login['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$login['name']])?$errors[$login['name']]:''; ?></td>    
</tr>   
<tr> 
  <td> <?php echo form_label('Password', $password['id']); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo form_password($password); ?> </td>
  <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($password['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$password['name']])?$errors[$password['name']]:''; ?></td>   
</tr>
```

The login form appears at the top left of the webpage. Is there any way to position this into the center of the page or move it around the page.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

I tried doing this:

```
<style>
  #content {
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto ;
    text-align:center;
  }
</style>
<div id='content'>
 <tr>

        <td><?php echo form_label($login_label, $login['id']); ?></td>

        <td><?php echo form_input($login); ?></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo form_error($login['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$login['name']])?$errors[$login['name']]:''; ?></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

This moved the login form down but not to the side. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, it is called `CSS`

Comment: Use `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `margin:10px;`.

Comment: I used the `0 auto` too,same issue.

Comment: you need to define width while using margin: auto 0; e.g width: 100%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the form in a div and move it with css (for simplicity style is in the view but you could have it as an external stylesheet):

```
<style>
  #content {
    width:500px;
    margin:0px auto;
  }
</style>
<div id='content'>
 {form goes here}
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my post...i tried what you suggested. The login form moved down, but not to the side. Any ideas?

Comment: could you post the output of the page on jsfiddle? It is a bit difficult with a partial page. I also notice there is no <table></table>. it may be that the container of the table is not wide enough.

Comment: I just posted the full code. Thanks for all the effort that you are putting into this.

Comment: well from what I see, it won't work because you are adding a div within a table. Centering would have worked if you were centering the whole table within that div or a div within a div. what you could do to center it without too many changes is adding an empty table cell before or adding padding to each table cell

Comment: Haha...That's one way of doing it. It worked, and that solved the problem, for now :P Thank you very much for your help.